# HttpClient - how to update http message header cookie with additional values

Tags: c#, http-get, dotnet-httpclient

I have to use WebAPI `HttpClient` class to send and receive `HttpRequestMessage` and `HttpResponseMessage`.

I am tracking multiple requests through same instance of `HttpClient` class (i.e. multiple requests for a particular sessionID). The first Get request creates SessionID; its `HttpResponseMessage` has sessionID, cookie header, etc. elements.

For the second request, I have to add additional data to returned cookie in the header of first request message. `HttpClient` class provides only two methods for Get - `GetAsync(URL)` and `SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage)`.

`HttpClient` class provides only two methods for GET message - `GetAsync` which takes only URI and hence doesn't seem useful. `SendAsync` takes `HttpRequestMessage` and here you cannot use `HttpClientHandler` without reintializing `HttpClient` class object.

*How do I update the cookie header and add additional information to the Get request message?*

Check following sample Get messages captured in Fiddler

## Request 1 sample

```
> GET //xxxx/xx/xxx/BrowseMaterials.aspx HTTP/1.1 
> Accept: text/html,
> application/xhtml+xml, */* Referer: //xxx/xx/xx/Home.aspx
> Accept-Language: en-US User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0;
> Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0) Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
> Connection: Keep-Alive Cookie: Client=MN;
> xxxx=SessionId=95ab57ca-59b0-4a13-9249-04a7f1251058&TeacherId=6584&StudentId=0&Name=DAC
> DemoTwo;
> querystring=querystring=http%3a%2f%xxxxx%2fLPN%2fTeacher%2fHome.aspx; 
> ASP.NET_SessionId=t1xadfmys5tmoz3bwnwginnw; search=; Mode=Teacher;
> TimeZoneOffset=5
```

## Request 2 sample

```
> Cookie: Client=MN;
> xxx=SessionId=95ab57ca-59b0-4a13-9249-04a7f1251058&TeacherId=6584&StudentId=0&Name=DAC
> DemoTwo;
> querystring=querystring=xxxx%3a%2f%2fdxxxxxxx%2fLPN%2fTeacher%2fBrowseMaterials.aspx;
> ASP.NET_SessionId=t1xadfmys5tmoz3bwnwginnw;
> search=viewall=1&grades=&materialType=6,1,2,3,4,5&itemSearchControl0=itm_att_Item
> FORMAT&itemSearchControl1=itm_att_Learning
> Modalities&itemSearchControl2=itm_att_Flesch-Kincaid Grade Level
> Readability&text=; Mode=Teacher; TimeZoneOffset=5
```

---

Please not, I am using existing copy of  HttpClient object "client". I cannot reinitialize it with HttpMessageHandler. Doing so will create new SessionID, which is not desired. I am using SessionID to track between subsequent Get/Post requests. 
Also, it is C# console app., simulating web requests as browsers do. Let me know if you have any additional questions. 
Thanks to all for your relevant comments.

```
C# code
```

Approach # 1
    HttpRequestMessage GETRequest = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, completeUrl);
    string additionalCookVal = "viewall=1&grades=&materialType=&itemSearchControl0=itm_att_Item FORMAT,SIM&itemSearchControl1=itm_att_Learning Modalities&itemSearchControl2=itm_att_Flesch-Kincaid Grade Level Readability&text=";
    GETRequest.Headers.Add("Cookie1", additionalCookVal); //this is silently ignored
    HttpResponseMessage GETResponse = client.SendAsync(GETRequest).Result;

Approach # 2
    var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(additionalCookVals); //additionalCookVals is a Dictionary object
    HttpRequestMessage GETRequest = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, completeUrl);
    GETRequest.Content = content;
    HttpResponseMessage GETResponse = client.SendAsync(GETRequest).Result;  // it fails saying content cannot be added to Get message.

Comment: In your original question, you've identified the second part as `Request 2 sample` but do you actually mean this is the cookie returned as part of Request 1?

Comment: I am confused as to what is being asked here.  Where do you want to modify the cookie?  Client side or server side?  And why in the world are you using HttpWebRequest AND HttpClient?  One or the other would seem appropriate, but not both.  You really need to explain the situation better.

Comment: Oh my.  I think I finally understand what you are trying to do.  It looks like you are trying to embed a form in the cookie and you want the client to edit the form that is embedded in the cookie.  Is that right?  If so, you need to explain why you want to do this.  Why not just use the body or query string to pass the form data?

Comment: Dash, Please see my additional problem decription.

Comment: Dan, I am not using HttpWebRequest at all. I don't know where you read that. Also, note that web requests are going through a C# console app.

Comment: Darrel, I have added more description on your GitHub link. Please check it.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/4659969